# Why is the where clause neglected

Tags: android, sqlite, operator-precedence

I am trying the following query:

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, asColumnsToReturn,
       "NotificationDateFor like ?
       OR FriendsName like ?" +"
       AND TypeNotification <> 'Event'
       AND RadioType <> '3'
       ORDER BY DateToNotify ASC",
       new String[] { value, value }, null,null, null);
```

However I observe that in this case the part which corresponds to:

```
AND TypeNotification <> 'Event' AND RadioType <> '3'
```

Is being neglected. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), AND has a higher precedence than OR, so a `NotificationDateFor` match is enough to select a row:

```
sqlite> select 1 or 0 and 0 and 0;
1
```

You have to use parentheses:

```
(NotificationDateFor LIKE ? OR FriendsName LIKE ?) AND TypeNotification <> 'Event' AND RadioType <> '3'
```

Comment: Clean, let me try that!